# Edit wordpress footer for Rara Business how?

Tags: wordpress, footer

I want to edit the footer of a WordPress theme called Rara Business. Basically get rid of the part that says "Rara Business or Rara ThemeImpulsado for WordPress."

I thought that editing footer.php I would find that text, but that's not the case.

The footer.php file looks like this:

?php
/**
 * The template for displaying the footer
 *
 * Contains the closing of the #content div and all content after.
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/#template-partials
 *
 * @package Rara_Business
 */

```
/**
 * After Content
 * 
 * @hooked rara_business_content_end - 20
*/

 do_action( 'rara_business_before_footer' ); 


/**
 * Footer
 * 
 * @hooked rara_business_footer_start  - 20
 * @hooked rara_business_footer_top    - 30
 * @hooked rara_business_footer_bottom - 40
 * @hooked rara_business_footer_end    - 50
*/

do_action( 'rara_business_footer' );



/**
 * After Footer
 * 
 * @hooked rara_business_page_end    - 20
*/
do_action( 'rara_business_after_footer' );

wp_footer(); ?>
```

I tried deleting do_action( 'rara_business_after_footer' ); but first is not what I want, and second, it causes some other errors.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Please find template-functions.php file inside your theme /rara-business/inc/template-functions.php

Go to line no: 1080

There you will find the way to edit the footer.

Another way it can be hidden by css by adding following class style file:

```
.copyright span.by{
    display:none;
}
```